# the difference between window.$ and $

Tags: javascript, jquery

the source code of Zepto:

```
var Zepto =(function(){...})()
window.Zepto = Zepto
window.$ === undefined && (window.$ = Zepto)
```

when I debug in chrome ,both of that point to the Zepto, and whats the exact difference between that?

Answer (score 1):

I think window.$ and $ are same Object, like window.setTimeout and setTimeout. they are global varible ,you can leave out window.  ps:sorry, my english is poor,

Answer (score 0):

in normal browser code $ is same as using window.$

Zepto code shown it sets window.$ only if it's not defined

Answer (score 0):

When you use a variable the system looks for it by walking up the scope chain. Starting at the local scope and ending at the global scope which is window.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
alert(123);

window.alert(123);
```

they are equal. alert 123. in browser environment, if y don't add function prefix, the default is the window prefix.

for your question, in Zepto，if window.$ isn't occupied that assigned to Zepto.